# Set checkboxes stated to checked based on array values in razor asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have foreach loop that generates three rows of 7 checkboxes in a row dynamically via the database.

```
              @foreach (var order in item.Items)
              {                                  
                    <ul>
                        @for (int j = 1; j < order.NumCheckboxes; j++)
                        {

                            <li>
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="check-@j" checked>
                                 <label for="check-@j>/label>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                    }
```

In the `order` variable, it contains a list of `OrderChecked` that contains the id of the checkboxes that have to be checked when populated dynamically.

The `order.NumCheckboxes` is the number of checkboxes to be set in a row.

The list of `OrderChecked` contains ids starting from index 0 up to 3 and each index has a number associated with it that represents the checkboxes that have to be checked.

My question is how can I set the state of checkboxes to be checked based on the value in `OrderChecked` in razor asp mvc ? Please help.

Comment: you have already used checked attribute. what is the problem? the description is a bit confusing.

Comment: I want to use the `checked` attribute based on  based on the value in `OrderChecked`

Comment: For clarification can you add the definitions for the models?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Populating checkboxes dynamically and set their checked state dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657035/populating-checkboxes-dynamically-and-set-their-checked-state-dynamically).