# Populating checkboxes dynamically and set their checked state dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a for loop that generates 7 checkboxes in a row dynamically as follows :

```
@for (int i = 1; k < order.Rows.length; i++) {
Row: @i
    <ul>
        @for (int j = 1; j < order.NumCheckboxes.length; j++)
        {

           <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-@j" checked>
                <label for="check-@j>/label>
           </li>
          }
    </ul>
}
```

Then I have another loop that contains the values of the checkboxes to be set checked. 
**Checkbox state loop**

```
@for(int k = 0; k < order.CheckboxChecked.length; k++) 
{
}
```

This loop contains the values that represents the checkboxes state (3, 5).

For example, in Row 1, 7 checkboxes are dynamically generated in a row and the 3rd and 5th checkboxes are checked. The loop Checkbox state sets the 3rd and 5th checkbox checked in the first row. And if in Row 2, the first checkbox is checked, the loop Checkbox state sets the 1st checkbox checked in the second row and so on.

Can someone please advise me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: It is not clear from your question how the different values for the checkboxes in each row come into the `CheckboxChecked` array. Basically your data is *two dimensional* rather than one dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with just one element, you can always just modify the HTMLInputElement's .checked property:

```
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = true;
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = false;
```

The benefit to using the .prop() and .attr() methods instead of this is that they will operate on all matched elements.